# how to remove wordpress traces from backend?

Tags: wordpress

I just want to remove some of wordpress images, labels and other notifications that is located at the backend. If the non-admin users logged in I want them not to see the wordpress logos, labels and notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is very simple , it can be done using some css trick.

```
#wp-admin-bar-wp-logo,#footer-left,.update-nag,#dashboard_right_now,
#dashboard_primary,#dashboard_quick_press, #contextual-help-link
{
display:none !important;
}
```

try to paste that in your css